# WSO2 ESB persist all files from multipart/form-data message

Tags: wso2, esb, multipartform-data

I am newbie in the ESB (I'm using **WSO2 ESB 4.8.1**) and I have some problems in order to save files from a multipart/form-data message.

I have an HTML form in which I pass some text fields (f.e. name, age, direction....) and some files in diferent formats (jpg, docx, pdf...) and those files can be long files (from Kb to more than 2Gb).

When I submit this form to WSO2 ESB, is receive by an API (could be a proxy too).

I want to save into a file system each file pass in the form.

I try it doing an API like this:

```
<api name="apiTest" context="/apiTest">
  <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/test">
    <inSequence>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
      <endpoint>
        <address uri="vfs:file:///home/files"/>
       </endpoint>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
    </faultSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

The HTML form is like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8280/apiTest/test" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""></br>
      age: <input type="text" name="age" value=""></br>
      file: <input type="file" name="file" size="40" multiple>
      file2: <input type="file" name="file2" size="40" multiple>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I modified axis2.xml in order to enable Builders:

```
<messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="multipart/related" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/pdf" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

and Formatters:

```
<messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"  class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="application/pdf"  class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

The result of the execution is a single file in */home/files* called '*file*' with the content like:

```
----------WebKitFormBoundaryAXu9AAL2pPEV5pUN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Joe
----------WebKitFormBoundaryAXu9AAL2pPEV5pUN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

54
----------WebKitFormBoundaryAXu9AAL2pPEV5pUN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-type: image/jpeg

       <<Here are a stream of bytes>>
----------WebKitFormBoundaryAXu9AAL2pPEV5pUN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="curriculum.pdf"
Content-type: application/pdf

       <<Here are a stream of bytes>>
----------WebKitFormBoundaryAXu9AAL2pPEV5pUN--
```

The result I want is at least two files called "*photo.jpg*" and "*curriculum.pdf*" in that path (/home/files)

Any way to do what I want?